# Format command invocation string with multiple options

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function `ping` that needs to pass a string of a format
`ping mpls ipv4 <ip here> <param name> <valiue> <param name> <valiue> ...`
to a testbed device's method.

```
def ping(device, ip_address, **kwargs):
    options = ['destination', 'dsmap', 'exp', 'fec-type', 'flags', 'force-explicit', 'interval', 'output', 'pad', 'repeat', 'reply', 'session', 'size', 'source', 'sweep', 'timeout', 'ttl', 'verbose']

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key in options:
            cmd ="ping mpls ipv4 {0} {1} {2}".format(ip_address, key, value)
        output = device.execute(cmd)
    return output
```

Example usage:

```
ping(device, ip, size='100', interval='10', sweep='100 1500 100')
```

`device` is a testbed device and `ip` is a string containing an IPv4 IP.

The problem is that it calls the `device.execute` once for every keyword argument I specify and only returns the last return value. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
valid_options = ('{} {}'.format(key, value)
                 for key, value in kwargs.items()
                 if key in options)
cmd_options = ' '.join(valid_options)
cmd = 'ping mpls ipv4 {} {}'.foramt(ip_address, cmd_options)
```

BTW I recommend you to learn about [generator expressions](//anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generator-expressions) and [itertools](//docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). They wold save you from the "pyramid of doom" antipattern (lots of netted loops and conditions) clearly visible in your `test_001` function (edited out of the current version of the question as irrelevant).